# How to check whether there is claim identity exist in the URL

Tags: url, matlab, matlab-figure

My purpose for this feature is to check whether there is 2 or 3...URLs hide within 1 URL, if yes then return 1, else return 0. e.g. www.applee.com/www.samsunge.com, http://www.samsungds.http://comwww.samsung.com

I have settled the importdata prob, but now I faced difficulty for checking the data below:(I have modify the 'is_double_url.m' file, but it return me the error)

http://encuestanavemotors.com.ar/doc/newgoogledoc2013/2013gdocs/
http://totalwhiteboard.com.au/.pp/0053d4ae3e2c78154d29d413c1236341/192.186.237.145/H/
http://www.wwwwwwwwwws2.com/
http://www.paypal.com.cy.cgi.bin.webscr.cmd.login.submit.dispatch.5885d80a1faee8d48a116ba977951b3435308b8c4.turningpoint.in/f044c94b4394939f4a1a75798875f78c/
http://www.celebramania.cl/web/cc/personal/cards/5d0d5c5af4f12c319d47872fabe11262/Pool=0/?cmd=_home&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e&ee=5cd428ee24c5037dda298a4762735a94
http://joannalindsay.com/wp-content/uploads/aloo/aaleor.php?bidderblocklogin&hc=1&hm=uk%601d72f%2Bj2b2vi%3C265bidderblocklogin&hc=1&hm=uk%601d72f%2Bj2b2vi%3C265bidderblocklogin&hc=1&hm=uk%601d72f%2Bj2b2vi%3C265
http://bluedominoes.com/~kosalbco/paypal.de/

is_double_url.m file

```
function out = is_double_url(url_path1)

f1 = strfind(url_path1,'www.');
if isempty(f1)
out = 0;
return;
end
f2 = strfind(url_path1,'/');
f3 = bsxfun(@minus,f2,f1');

count_dots = zeros(size(f3,1),1);
for k = 1:size(f3,1)
[x,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);
str2 = url_path1(f1(k):f2(y));
if ~isempty(strfind(str2,'..'))
    continue
end
count_dots(k) = nnz(strfind(str2,'.'));
end
out = ~any(count_dots(2:end)<2);

if any(strfind(url_path1,'://')>f2(1))
out = true;
end

return;
```

f10.m file
    data = importdata('url');
    [sizeData b] = size(data);

```
for i = 1:sizeData
feature10(i) = is_double_url(data{i});

end
```

Comment: What do you want to count as a URL? Does it have to include `www`? Does it have to include `.com`? Does it have to include `http://`, or `https://`? What about the many other different forms of URL? I think you need to specify your question more clearly.

Comment: Use [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to detect certain delimiters/keywords like _.com_, _http://_, _www._ and so on that will indicate another URL. Then you can simply detect multiples of these keywords

Comment: The example website you're using here is reported by Chrome to be a phishing site. Why is that? I haven't come across many suppliers of corset-making equipment that use MATLAB.

Comment: @Sam Roberts, there have many condition need to check. I am doing research with phishing feature, but don't worry, it juz 1 of the example.

Comment: @user3340270 For the safety of people attempting to answer your question, you could maybe replace the URL of phishing site with `example.com`.

Comment: @SamRoberts, do u have any idea for the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
function out = is_double_url(url_path1)

if url_path1(end)~='/'
    url_path1(end+1)='/';
end

url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//','//www.');
url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//www.www.','//www.');

f1 = strfind(url_path1,'www.');
if numel(f1)<2
    out = false;
else
    f2 = strfind(url_path1,'/');
    f3 = bsxfun(@minus,f2,f1');

    count_dots = zeros(size(f3,1),1);
    for k = 1:size(f3,1)
        [~,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);
        str2 = url_path1(f1(k):f2(y));
        if ~isempty(strfind(str2,'..'))
            continue
        end
        count_dots(k) = nnz(strfind(str2,'.'));
    end
    out = ~any(count_dots(2:end)<2);

    if any(strfind(url_path1,'://')>f2(1))
        out = true;
    end
end

return;
```

**Runs**

```
is_double_url('http://www.farthingalescorsetmakingsupplies.com/files/files/www.apple.com/')

is_double_url('http://www.farthingalescorsetmakingsupplies.com/files/files/www.com/')

is_double_url('http://www.farthingalescorsetmakingsupplies.com/files/files/https://www.com/')

is_double_url('http://www.farthingalescorsetmakingsupplies.com/files/files/https://www.dfdsf.my/')


Returns - 1 0 1 1 respectively.
```

If you have a list of URLs in a text file , use this to do checking for each of them -

```
fid = fopen('text2.txt'); %% 'text2.txt' has the urls on line by line basis
C = textscan(fid, '%s\n');
fclose(fid);

for k = 1:numel(C{1})
    out(k) = is_double_url(C{1}{k}); %%// out stores the condition checked statuses
end
```

Comment: yes, that exactly what I want 4 the output. Why do I get an error for this? e.g.??? Error: File: is_double_url.m Line: 9 Column: 7
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: ' [~,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);'--->it show me parse error at ')'usage might be invalid for Matlab syntax

Comment: Replace that with this `[x,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);`. It could be a MATLAB old version issue.

Comment: I have try to copy paste the code at script there, then save as 'is_double_url.m', after that paste 'is_double_url('http://www.farthingalescorsetmakingsupplies.com/files/files/www.apple.com/')' in command window, but stil return me the error. Anything I have wrongly done?

Comment: May I ask how to import my data instead of showing the 4 URL in command window? I use '>> data=importdata('URL');
>> is_double_url(data)', but it there is difficulty in 'bsxfun', it show me the error '??? Error using ==> bsxfun
Operands must be numeric arrays.

Error in ==> is_double_url at 5
f3 = bsxfun(@minus,f2,f1');'

Comment: my'data' is in <100x1 cell>

Comment: `is_double_url(URL)` expects URL only as the input to it, nothing else should be given to it. If you wish to import webpage date into some variable, try 'urlread' - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: any idea to modify the above code? That is d last part for this already, d 'is_double_URL.m' & 'f10.m' file are match for now, but the checking got some prob, I do modify but cant get the results. Due to I have a lots of data, so need to consider a lot while checking.

Comment: Edited for new requirements!

Comment: thx, but why do i get this error? "??? Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in ==> f10 at 6
    out(k) = is_double_url(C{1}{k}); %%// out stores the condition checked statuses"

Is that any mistake I have did?
I type this at command window ">> is_double_url('URL')

ans =

     0"
I cannot get the list of each of that with e.g.[1 0 0 1 0 1]

Comment: hi Divakar, can i ask d last question at here....
why do I get error when I use this "url_path1 = importdata('DATA\URL\training_URL')
out = is_double_url(url_path1); ", I test this program can run in cmd window, but if I want to use import method like here, it show me the error. I do try in other program for import, it works...anything that I have did wrong?